# Can we use php web services in java?

Tags: java, php, web-services, spring-mvc

I have a web application in JAVA (Spring MVC framework) and I want to connect to a website and use its web services which wrote in php, is it possible ? if yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what language one used to create a webservice. You can talk to any webservice by agreeing on how it exchanges messages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring integrates well with Apache Axis: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html

To consume web services with Spring you can use JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean  to create a client proxy: http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/03/writing-and-testing-jax-ws-clients.html

From Spring in Action, here's how you'd configure an example web service proxy bean:

```
<bean id="spitterService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean"
    p:wsdlDocumentUrl="http://localhost:8080/services/SpitterService?wsdl"
    p:serviceName="spitterService" p:portName="spitterServiceHttpPort" 
    p:serviceInterface="com.habuma.spitter.service.SpitterService" 
    p:namespaceUri="http://spitter.com"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The beautiful thing about web services, and web services are beautiful things, their hosts are made with wsdl's, their client is made in Spring! (Totally [stole](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJFyz73MRcg) that from the mouse (just a warning, as per the comments, this rhyme is not to be used as an authoritative *anything*. It is an attempt at humor by someone who was excessively tired at 3 AM because of Win 7 issues))

Web services are language agnostic -- the only thing which matters is that they are up and running (and serving valid outputs), not that they are using technology X, Y, or Z. Theoretically, you could even have a webservice running on something written in [Piet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet_%28programming_language%29) or [Brainf*ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).

A tutorial on how to create a client can be found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html).

Comment: Bit misleading - webservice is a generic term for machine to machine communication over HTTP - but WSDL is specific to the SOAP protocol running on top of a webservice. There are other protocols used in webservices including JSON and serialized PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use [CWSDLGeneratorDocument.php](https://github.com/Taron133/CWSDLGeneratorDocument) for generate WSDL file in DOCUMENT/LITERAl style and use standart library JAX-WS in java 1.7.